# Revealing Module Alternative or Variation for Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, design-patterns, jasmine

#### Overview

I've been using the Revealing Module Pattern for a few months and I'm looking for an alternative or variation on this pattern that will solve *both* issues I'm currently having with event handlers and testability.  I know I could come up with some combination of what I have below to solve my problem, but I'm hoping to find a clean alternative that I could use consistently that addresses both of my current concerns.

#### Revealing Module Pattern

So in this example, I have no issues with event handlers, but I can't mock calls to functions 
within functions to test in isolation:

```
var Lion = (function () {

  // Reference to rawr works as expected when the click event is triggered
  function watch() {
    document.addEventListener('click', rawr);
  }

  function rawr() {
    console.log('rawr');
  }

  function attack() {
    console.log('attack');
  }

  /*
   * Can't test goCrazy() in isolation.  Mocking rawr() and attack()
   * has no effect as demonstrated below.
   */
  function goCrazy() {
    rawr();
    attack();

    // Important "crazy" logic
  }

  return {
    watch: watch,
    rawr: rawr,
    attack: attack,
    goCrazy: goCrazy
  };
}());

module.exports = Lion;
```

#### Example Test Case (Jasmine)

```
describe('Mock Check', function () {

  it('should mock rawr() and attack() and test only goCrazy logic', function () {
    var lion = require('Lion');

    spyOn(lion, 'rawr').and.reutrnValue(true);  
    spyOn(lion, 'attack').and.reutrnValue(true);  

    var crazy = lion.goCrazy();

    expect(lion.rawr).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <-- Fails
    expect(lion.attack).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <-- Fails

    // can't test goCrazy() logic in isolation :(
  });
});
```

#### Same Module using `this` instead and invoked using `new`

In this example, I can successfully mock calls to functions within functions, but if I attempt to add an event handler, `this` becomes `undefined` when the event is triggered.

```
var Lion = function () {

  // Reference to 'this' becomes undefined when event is triggered
  this.watch = function () {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.rawr);
  }

  this.rawr = function () {
    console.log('rawr');
  }

  this.attack = function () {
    console.log('attack');
  }

  /*
   * Can successfully test goCrazy() in isolation by being able to mock 
   * rawr() and attack() as needed
   */
  this.goCrazy = function () {
    this.rawr();
    this.attack();

    // Important "crazy" logic
  }
};

module.exports = Lion;
```

#### Example Test Case (Jasmine)

```
describe('Mock Check', function () {

  it('should mock rawr() and attack() and test only goCrazy logic', function () {
    var Lion = require('Lion');
    var lion = new Lion();

    spyOn(lion, 'rawr').and.reutrnValue(true);  
    spyOn(lion, 'attack').and.reutrnValue(true);  

    var crazy = lion.goCrazy();

    expect(lion.rawr).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <-- Success
    expect(lion.attack).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <-- Success

    // testing goCrazy logic in isolation :)
  });
});
```

Thanks for your time.  If any clarification is necessary, let me know and I'll modify my post.

Comment: Where and how are you invoking `watch`?

Comment: Let's just say I call lion.watch() in another module (using Browserify and expecting a click in the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem here is that, the event handler loses the context of the current object. You can bind it like this

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.rawr.bind(this));
```

This will make sure that whenever the `rawr` is invoked, the `this` inside `rawr` corresponds to the `lion` object which you created.

Comment: Ah, that's the ticket.  Thank you so much!